# running asyncio in Flask with mongoengine

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, flask, python-asyncio

I wanted to run four mongo queries simultaneously, wait for the results, then return the results to the user in an API endpoint in Flask.  I was trying to use a coroutine in mongo and do something like:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def mongo_query(object_type):
    if object_type == 'Type1':
        return Type1.objects[:10]
    elif object_type == 'Type2':
        return Type2.objects[:10]
    return Type3.objects[:10]
```

And then have a Flask endpoint with some logic like:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
tasks = [asyncio.async(mongo_query(object_type)) for object_type in ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3']]
return loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

I keep getting errors that say `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-4'.` which I'm not sure how to remedy this.  I realize Flask is WSGI so async might not make sense, but I was trying to introduce asyncio to my application with very little luck.

The intent is to handle multiple mongo queries simultaneously, wait for them all to resolve, then return the results rather than do it synchronously.  Would threading work better for a Flask app, or is there a way to remedy this error?

Comment: You don't await (or in this particular case `yield from`) anywhere so your queries are going to run consecutively.

Comment: when I run this now, the error I get states: 
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-4' in reference to `asyncio.new_event_loop()`